# 3D CSS scene not displaying properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

I'm working on a 3D "room" using CSS transform3d and rotate3d, and using buttons to move and rotate the scene by modifying the transforms/rotates via Javascript.

Simplified version of the structure:

```
<body style="perspective:500px; transform-style:preserve-3d;">
    <div id="hallway">
        <div id="backwall" style="transform:translatez(2000px)"></div>
        <div id="ceiling" style="transform:rotatex(-90deg)"></div>
        <div id="left-wall" style="transform:rotatey(-90deg)"></div>
        <div id="right-wall" style="transform:rotatey(90deg)"></div>
        <div id="floor" style="transform:rotatex(90deg)"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons"></div>
</body>
```

The left and right buttons apply `transform:rotatey` to `#hallway` in increments of 20deg, the forward and backward buttons apply `transform:translate` etc..

In Chrome and Firefox, the "room" works perfectly.  However in Safari it is almost entirely invisible, only displaying tiny random slivers of the walls when the scene is rotated or moved.  I know Safari must handle *some* 3D CSS effect differently than the mainstream browsers, but I've gone through several times and I cannot figure out which effect it is.  Any ideas?

The site is up at http://vanderstank.church/hallwayway.html

Comment: Could you please add the relevant css? So that we can actually reproduce it?

Comment: @RakeshGR I've included what I thought was the "relevant css" already... there are roughly 90 lines of CSS and 70 lines of Javascript, I figured including all that would be overkill and get my question downvoted.  Should I paste the entire source code?  Or maybe just link to an online copy of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply fix the css below**

```
* { box-sizing:border-box; transform-style:preserve-3d; }
```

**to**

```
body > * { box-sizing:border-box; transform-style:preserve-3d; }
```

`<body>` should not give transform-style attribute, i think it will cause the scene disapper in safari.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Thank you, that's it! Any insight on to why this happens?